# `render` prop in react router is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I tried using `render` in place of `component` but it's not working .`

```
<Router  history={browserHistory} >
  <Route path="/" render={() => <div>Home</div>}/>
</Router>
```

Comment: Can you specify which version of react-router are you using? If you are using react-routerV4, then it does not accept `history` as a props. You can also check if there is any error in the console.

Comment: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start - Details

Answer (score 0):

I removed `history` and added the following code to fix it

`BrowserRouter as Router`from `react-router-dom`